# How can you show the error value of Println if Println gets error if you can put it as variable?

Tags: go

It says:

Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard output. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.

How do I create/test an error and show the error if it is stored in b
when I run the program it shows "nil" since no error, how can i show any error?

```
  a,b :=fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
https://play.golang.org/p/8Cjb2Sfunx7
```

Comment: why do you need to get an error from fmt.Println func?

Comment: @novalagung Im learning GO so I want to know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual to have Println errors, the docs also this. But if you are really interesting in doing a test of it, it works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    const name, age = "Kim", 22
    os.Stdout.Close()
    _, err := fmt.Println(name, "is", age, "years old.")
    log.Fatal(err)

}
```

In order to artificially trigger an error we are closing the default Stdout file, used by Println. See the [`os` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables).

Comment: Anything I fmt.Println after os.Stdout.Close won't get printed simulating that Println doesnt work? Is my understanding correct? I did test it seems to work https://play.golang.org/p/ZZcpzvlWLf9

Comment: Yes it is! Its closed, nothing will be written on console